# How to replace every letter in a python string with another?

Tags: python, replace

```py
s = 'word'
t = s.replace('a','g')
t = s.replace('b','h')
t = s.replace('c','a')
t = s.replace('d','j')
t = s.replace('e','t')
t = s.replace('f','k')
t = s.replace('g','l')
t = s.replace('h','q')
t = s.replace('i','f')
t = s.replace('j','e')
t = s.replace('k','r')
t = s.replace('l','w')
t = s.replace('m','b')
t = s.replace('n','v')
t = s.replace('o','u')
t = s.replace('t','i')
t = s.replace('q','t')
t = s.replace('r','c')
t = s.replace('s','n')
t = s.replace('t','m')
t = s.replace('u','z')
t = s.replace('v','x')
t = s.replace('w','y')
t = s.replace('x','o')
t = s.replace('y','s')
t = s.replace('z','d')
print(t)
```

I'm trying to replace every letter of a string with another letter to print something completely different, eg: "python" ends up to be "fhoeyd".

This code doesn't work if it includes letters to replace that aren't in the word. I can't find a way to make it work, even though I know the reason why. I just dont know how to fix it. I'm new to python, so if anyone could help that would be great.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ?? are you trying to shift the alphabet .. something like the Caesar cipher ?

Comment: [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this one:

```
list_A = ['w','o','r','l','d']
list_B = ['y','u','c','w','j']

string = 'world'
string_fin = ''

for s in string:
    for i, j in zip (list_A, list_B):
        if s == i:
            string_fin += j

print(string_fin)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```
import string
import random

letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
word = "python"

for letter in word:
  word = word.replace(letter, random.choice(letters))

word
```

Output -

```
zufmqr
```

Becuase this code randomly replaces a letter with another, each time your output would be different. To have a consistent output set a seed using `random.seed()` and pass any number of your choice in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several ways.

#### 1. convert every character in ASCII add a number and convert the result into characters, but you might end with some special characters like "#@$%^?"

`letter = chr(ord(ch) + 6)` I get the character `ch` convert it to the ASCII equivalent, add 6 and use `chr()` to convert the result into a string

```
input_string = input("input a string: ")

result = []

for ch in input_string:
    new_ch = chr(ord(ch) + 6)
    result.append(new_ch)

print("".join(result))
```

#### 2. Use the random and string library.

```
import string 
import random 


characters = string.ascii_lowercase
string = input("input a sentece: ")
result = []

for ch in string:
    letter = random.choice(characters)
    result.append(letter)

print("".join(result))
```

I will suggest going for the second option since provide some random element if the idea is to use it for a password generator.